# PowerShell script with looping can not work after encryption

Tags: sql, powershell, loops, encryption

I have powershell script with looping. But After I encrypt the script. The looping is always running and never stop.
Anyone can help please. THank you

```
Function 101_Pr
{
    Write-Host " 101_Pr"
}

Function CleanUp
{
    Write-Host "CleanUp"
}
Function Image
{

$Stoploop = $false
[int]$Retrycount = "0"
do {
    try {
        $Get = "123AB"
        $connectionString = "Server=$IP;uid=$UID;pwd=$Pswd;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=False;"
        Write-Host $connectionString
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $connection.Open()

        $query = "select Number='$Get'"
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $query
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
        $table.Load($result)

        [array] $DB = $table.Number
        Write-Host "Result: $DB"

        if($null -ne $DB)
        {
            $Stoploop = $true

           101_Pr
            break
        }
        }
    catch {

            if ($Retrycount -gt 2)
            {
                Write-Host "Could not get after 3 retrys."
                $Stoploop = $true

                CleanUp

                break

            }
            else{
                Write-Host "Retry"
                Start-Sleep -s 1
                $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
            }
            }
        }
        While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
}


Image
```

The output is always print this  Write-Host $connectionString
I use this script for encryption
ps2exe.ps1

anyone can help really appreciated. THank you

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `0` in `[int]$Retrycount = "0"`. Also, I don't understand this `[array] $DB = $table. Number` What's with the space between `$table.` and `Number`?

Comment: @Theo I already remove the quotes. But still the same output, the looping always running and never stop. It should be without space [array] $DB = $table Number